# unable to download map by get_map() function

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I need a help with get_map Function
, Every time i use it , i can't download the the map

Example:

```
get_map('Egypt',zoom = 'auto')
```

> Error in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
>     cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Egypt&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
>     cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Egypt&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I decided to use leaflet package instead of it since this service unfortunately became not free

Answer (score 1):

`ggmap` is using Google Maps as its standard map source.

At the moment, the Google Maps API that `ggmap` is connecting to needs lon/lat coordinates (e.g., `location = c(16.3738,48.2082)` - **not** a location name) and a functioning and registered Google Maps API key (that you register via `register_google(key = "...")` in every new session) to get a map.

So, the full code for you would be

```r
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "...") # with your billing-enabled API key entered here
map <- get_map(location = c(31.2357,30.0444), zoom = 5)
ggmap(map)
```

[image: egypt plot]

For further troubleshooting pointers, see [this issue on Github](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/51).